# What did Jesus say about the end times?

Tags: life-of-jesus, biblical-basis, eschatology, gospels

Between the fighting in Israel, [blood moons](http://www.cbn.com/cbnnews/insideisrael/2014/February/Divine-Sign-for-Israel-Hagee-Explains-Blood-Moons/), and [the Harbinger](http://www.cbn.com/tv/1471942971001), there has been a lot of chatter about the end times on my radar lately. Natural disasters are, too, discussed as omens of the end. I have tried not to bother too much with it, but I'm curious.

What did Jesus have to say about the end times? Did He give specifics, or discuss it in parables? I do recall Him saying that no one (Himself included) knows when it will be... But does He give any indication as to what will happen?

Comment: Meta discussion about this question [here](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3923/4277).

Comment: Here are the three verses where the moon turns the color of blood: http://www.blueletterbible.org/search/search.cfm?Criteria=moon+blood&t=KJV#s=s_primary_0_1

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based, as people widely disagree about which teachings of Jesus, if any, relate to the end of the world (as opposed to the fall of Jerusalem, for example).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jesus' most clear statements on the end times are in Matthew 24.  You can see for yourself what He said.

I don't see anything about "blood moons" here, but this passage is far from the only passage in Scripture that addresses the end times.  A full answer addressing eschatology would be **far*** too large to this site.  Many books have been written on the subject, so I'm sticking to Jesus' words, as asked.

> 1 And Jesus went out, and departed from the temple: and his disciples
>   came to him for to shew him the buildings of the temple.
>
> 2 And Jesus said unto them, See ye not all these things? verily I say
>   unto you, There shall not be left here one stone upon another, that
>   shall not be thrown down.
>
> 3 And as he sat upon the mount of Olives, the disciples came unto him
>   privately, saying, Tell us, when shall these things be? and what shall
>   be the sign of thy coming, and of the end of the world?
>
> 4 And Jesus answered and said unto them, Take heed that no man deceive
>   you.
>
> 5 For many shall come in my name, saying, I am Christ; and shall
>   deceive many.
>
> 6 And ye shall hear of wars and rumours of wars: see that ye be not
>   troubled: for all these things must come to pass, but the end is not
>   yet.
>
> 7 For nation shall rise against nation, and kingdom against kingdom:
>   and there shall be famines, and pestilences, and earthquakes, in
>   divers places.
>
> 8 All these are the beginning of sorrows.
>
> 9 Then shall they deliver you up to be afflicted, and shall kill you:
>   and ye shall be hated of all nations for my name's sake.
>
> 10 And then shall many be offended, and shall betray one another, and
>   shall hate one another.
>
> 11 And many false prophets shall rise, and shall deceive many.
>
> 12 And because iniquity shall abound, the love of many shall wax cold.
>
> 13 But he that shall endure unto the end, the same shall be saved.
>
> 14 And this gospel of the kingdom shall be preached in all the world
>   for a witness unto all nations; and then shall the end come.
>
> 15 When ye therefore shall see the abomination of desolation, spoken
>   of by Daniel the prophet, stand in the holy place, (whoso readeth, let
>   him understand:)
>
> 16 Then let them which be in Judaea flee into the mountains:
>
> 17 Let him which is on the housetop not come down to take any thing
>   out of his house:
>
> 18 Neither let him which is in the field return back to take his
>   clothes.
>
> 19 And woe unto them that are with child, and to them that give suck
>   in those days!
>
> 20 But pray ye that your flight be not in the winter, neither on the
>   sabbath day:
>
> 21 For then shall be great tribulation, such as was not since the
>   beginning of the world to this time, no, nor ever shall be.
>
> 22 And except those days should be shortened, there should no flesh be
>   saved: but for the elect's sake those days shall be shortened.
>
> 23 Then if any man shall say unto you, Lo, here is Christ, or there;
>   believe it not.
>
> 24 For there shall arise false Christs, and false prophets, and shall
>   shew great signs and wonders; insomuch that, if it were possible, they
>   shall deceive the very elect.
>
> 25 Behold, I have told you before.
>
> 26 Wherefore if they shall say unto you, Behold, he is in the desert;
>   go not forth: behold, he is in the secret chambers; believe it not.
>
> 27 For as the lightning cometh out of the east, and shineth even unto
>   the west; so shall also the coming of the Son of man be.
>
> 28 For wheresoever the carcase is, there will the eagles be gathered
>   together.
>
> 29 Immediately after the tribulation of those days shall the sun be
>   darkened, and the moon shall not give her light, and the stars shall
>   fall from heaven, and the powers of the heavens shall be shaken:
>
> 30 And then shall appear the sign of the Son of man in heaven: and
>   then shall all the tribes of the earth mourn, and they shall see the
>   Son of man coming in the clouds of heaven with power and great glory.
>
> 31 And he shall send his angels with a great sound of a trumpet, and
>   they shall gather together his elect from the four winds, from one end
>   of heaven to the other.
>
> 32 Now learn a parable of the fig tree; When his branch is yet tender,
>   and putteth forth leaves, ye know that summer is nigh:
>
> 33 So likewise ye, when ye shall see all these things, know that it is
>   near, even at the doors.
>
> 34 Verily I say unto you, This generation shall not pass, till all
>   these things be fulfilled.
>
> 35 Heaven and earth shall pass away, but my words shall not pass away.
>
> 36 But of that day and hour knoweth no man, no, not the angels of
>   heaven, but my Father only.
>
> 37 But as the days of Noah were, so shall also the coming of the Son
>   of man be.
>
> 38 For as in the days that were before the flood they were eating and
>   drinking, marrying and giving in marriage, until the day that Noe
>   entered into the ark,
>
> 39 And knew not until the flood came, and took them all away; so shall
>   also the coming of the Son of man be.
>
> 40 Then shall two be in the field; the one shall be taken, and the
>   other left.
>
> 41 Two women shall be grinding at the mill; the one shall be taken,
>   and the other left.
>
> 42 Watch therefore: for ye know not what hour your Lord doth come.
>
> 43 But know this, that if the goodman of the house had known in what
>   watch the thief would come, he would have watched, and would not have
>   suffered his house to be broken up.
>
> 44 Therefore be ye also ready: for in such an hour as ye think not the
>   Son of man cometh.
>
> 45 Who then is a faithful and wise servant, whom his lord hath made
>   ruler over his household, to give them meat in due season?
>
> 46 Blessed is that servant, whom his lord when he cometh shall find so
>   doing.
>
> 47 Verily I say unto you, That he shall make him ruler over all his
>   goods.
>
> 48 But and if that evil servant shall say in his heart, My lord
>   delayeth his coming;
>
> 49 And shall begin to smite his fellowservants, and to eat and drink
>   with the drunken;
>
> 50 The lord of that servant shall come in a day when he looketh not
>   for him, and in an hour that he is not aware of,
>
> 51 And shall cut him asunder, and appoint him his portion with the
>   hypocrites: there shall be weeping and gnashing of teeth.
>
> **King James Version (KJV)**

Also, from Luke 21: (This time NIV)

> 5 Some of his disciples were remarking about how the temple was adorned
>   with beautiful stones and with gifts dedicated to God. But Jesus said,
>   6 “As for what you see here, the time will come when not one stone will
>   be left on another; every one of them will be thrown down.”
>
> 7 “Teacher,” they asked, “when will these things happen? And what will
>   be the sign that they are about to take place?”
>
> 8 He replied: “Watch out that you are not deceived. For many will come
>   in my name, claiming, ‘I am he,’ and, ‘The time is near.’ Do not
>   follow them. 9 When you hear of wars and uprisings, do not be
>   frightened. These things must happen first, but the end will not come
>   right away.”
>
> 10 Then he said to them: “Nation will rise against nation, and kingdom
>   against kingdom. 11 There will be great earthquakes, famines and
>   pestilences in various places, and fearful events and great signs from
>   heaven.
>
> 12 “But before all this, they will seize you and persecute you. They
>   will hand you over to synagogues and put you in prison, and you will
>   be brought before kings and governors, and all on account of my name.
>   13 And so you will bear testimony to me. 14 But make up your mind not to
>   worry beforehand how you will defend yourselves. 15 For I will give you
>   words and wisdom that none of your adversaries will be able to resist
>   or contradict. 16 You will be betrayed even by parents, brothers and
>   sisters, relatives and friends, and they will put some of you to
>   death. 17 Everyone will hate you because of me. 18 But not a hair of
>   your head will perish. 19 Stand firm, and you will win life.
>
> 20 “When you see Jerusalem being surrounded by armies, you will know
>   that its desolation is near. 21 Then let those who are in Judea flee to
>   the mountains, let those in the city get out, and let those in the
>   country not enter the city. 22 For this is the time of punishment in
>   fulfillment of all that has been written. 23 How dreadful it will be in
>   those days for pregnant women and nursing mothers! There will be great
>   distress in the land and wrath against this people. 24 They will fall
>   by the sword and will be taken as prisoners to all the nations.
>   Jerusalem will be trampled on by the Gentiles until the times of the
>   Gentiles are fulfilled.
>
> 25 “There will be signs in the sun, moon and stars. On the earth,
>   nations will be in anguish and perplexity at the roaring and tossing
>   of the sea. 26 People will faint from terror, apprehensive of what is
>   coming on the world, for the heavenly bodies will be shaken. 27 At that
>   time they will see the Son of Man coming in a cloud with power and
>   great glory. 28 When these things begin to take place, stand up and
>   lift up your heads, because your redemption is drawing near.”
>
> 29 He told them this parable: “Look at the fig tree and all the trees.
>   30 When they sprout leaves, you can see for yourselves and know that
>   summer is near. 31 Even so, when you see these things happening, you
>   know that the kingdom of God is near.
>
> 32 “Truly I tell you, this generation will certainly not pass away
>   until all these things have happened. 33 Heaven and earth will pass
>   away, but my words will never pass away.
>
> 34 “Be careful, or your hearts will be weighed down with carousing,
>   drunkenness and the anxieties of life, and that day will close on you
>   suddenly like a trap. 35 For it will come on all those who live on the
>   face of the whole earth. 36 Be always on the watch, and pray that you
>   may be able to escape all that is about to happen, and that you may be
>   able to stand before the Son of Man.”
>
> 37 Each day Jesus was teaching at the temple, and each evening he went
>   out to spend the night on the hill called the Mount of Olives, 38and
>   all the people came early in the morning to hear him at the temple.

Answer (score 0):

Navarre Bible New Testament Compact Edition note on [MK 13:3-37](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark+13%3A3-37&version=RSVCE) has:

> The opening verses (vv.5-13) refer to "the beginnings of the
>   sufferings" (v.8):the tribulation which will start prior to the
>   destruction of Jerusalem (vv.6-8) is like the tribulation that
>   Christians will experience (vv.9-13). In both cases, our LORD's
>   instruction is an invitation to hope.
>
> The discourse then goes on (vv.14-27) to describe the key moment - the
>   Judgment. The "desolating sacrilege" (v.14) is an expression taken
>   from prophet Daniel
>   ([Dan:27](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel+9%3A27&version=RSVCE))
>   referring to the profantion of the temple (cf. [1 Mac
>   1:54](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Maccabees+1%3A54&version=RSVCE)).
>   Our LORD uses the expression to sum up the desperate situation the
>   inhabitants of Jesrusalem will find themselves in (vv.14-20) at that
>   time. **Christians will experience similar anguish (vv.21-25) prior to
>   the coming of the Son of man in glory (vv.26-27).**
>
> The final verses (vv.28-37) indicate the attitude Christ's disciples
>   should have (v.37); they should be watchful, vigilant (vv.33, 35, 37).
>   One thing is certain: the LORD will come, just as surely as the fig
>   tree goes through its seasons, just as the owner of the house will
>   return as promised. The disciples must be vigilant. "He wished to hide
>   this from us so that we might remain on our guard and be aware that
>   this might happen to us during our life. He said very clearly that he
>   would come gaian, but without stating at what moment. Thus, through
>   all generations and at all times his coming is awaited ardently" (St.
>   Ephrem, *Super Diatess.*, 18, 15-17). In the liturgy of Advent, the
>   Church encourages us to keep up this watchfulness.

---

**So, a clear sign is *the desolating sacrilege* being *set up* [in Rome?]**

---

*I do recall Him saying that no one (Himself included) knows when it will be*

The Catholic Church teaches that *not knowing* meant *not meant to reveal*:

> [Catechism of the Church,
>   474](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p122a3p1.htm#474)
>   By its union to the divine wisdom in the person of the Word incarnate,
>   Christ enjoyed in his human knowledge the fullness of understanding of
>   the eternal plans he had come to reveal. [Cf. Mk 8:31; 9:31; 10:33-34;
>   14:18-20, 26-30.]. What he admitted to not knowing in this area, he
>   elsewhere declared himself not sent to reveal. [Cf. Mk 13:32, Acts
>   1:7.].

Answer (score -1):

1)  Humanity would be well on its way to [destroying itself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VH3AlPmavDk&list=PLSIQ5Y5AZnvgtYUmv4lUXABVLUJgYd8nS).

> "And unless those days had been shortened, no flesh should be saved:
>   but for the sake of the elect those days shall be shortened."  Matt 24:22

2) There will be very few people possessing the [true faith](http://www.mostholyfamilymonastery.com/audio/papacy.mp3) at the end of the world

> I say to you, that he will quickly revenge them. But yet the Son of
>   man, when he cometh, shall he find, think you, faith on earth?

3) People will be as wicked at the end as they were right before the Flood

> And as it came to pass in the days of Noe, so shall it be also in the
>   days of the Son of man Luke 17:26

Comment: I didn't -1, but this is an ironically *apocalyptic* view...